# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '|'

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

There are two database connection in project. 
1. oracle database
2. mssql database

Database connection is OK. Issue is when data transferred/inserted in one database[oracle] then it is display error and same time data inserted in another database[mssql] successfully.Insert query is fine but there is another query which is generate sequesnce number. There have problem.

This is the query which belongs to oracle database

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT 'AK'||LPAD(adds_seq.NEXTVAL,13, '0') adds_seq_no     FROM sys.dual ",String.class);
```

Error is :

```
SELECT 'AK'||LPAD(adds_seq.NEXTVAL,13, '0') adds_seq_no     FROM sys.dual ",String.class ]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '|'.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
```

It is working well before when there is no mssql connection.

Below query is for oracle database. When I tried to change code like this:

```
String sql = " SELECT 'AK'||LPAD(adds_seq.NEXTVAL,13, '0') adds_seq_no     FROM sys.dual";
String adSeqNum = null;
    try {
            adSeqNum = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return addSeqNum;
```

then the error is

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ADDSS_HST"."ADDS_SEQ_NO")
```

1.Can you guide me how to solve this issue?

2.Can you please give me example for how to do separate database connection on one java file?

Comment: What values are you inserting?  Sounds like the statement is trying to put `NULL` into the column `ADDS_SEQ_NO` on the `ADDSS_HST` table in the Oracle database, but it is a `NOT NULL` column.

Answer (score 1):

The `"Incorrect syntax near '|'"` happens because you are sending the Oracle statement `"SELECT 'AK'||LPAD(adds_seq.NEXTVAL,13, '0') adds_seq_no FROM sys.dual "` to the MSSQL server connection.

The second error, `cannot insert null into "ADDSS_HST"."ADDS_SEQ_NO"` I suspect happens because before the posted sql that selects from the sequence, you are inserting records into ADDSS_HST table.  Is this correct?  If so, I recommend that you put the code that generates adds_seq_no into a trigger like the one below (adjust names for your needs):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "APPLICATION_BI_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON APPLICATION
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN
  if :new.application_id is null then 
    // if no value was given in insert statement for column application_id 

    SELECT APP_WEB_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.application_id FROM dual;
    // select a value from sequence into :NEW.application_id 

  end if;

END;
/
```